# VVV 403 Forbidden error (vagrant)

Tags: apache, nginx, vagrant, http-status-code-403, vvvv

I have project that I've been working on for a while using VVV on vagrant. Suddenly after running vagrant up, everything looks perfect but when I try to load the page, I get the following message:

403 Forbidden
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

I tried multiple solutions (see the list) that I found here and on github too. However, non of them fixed my problem.

- https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/505
- https://github.com/aliso/vvv-site-wizard/issues/23
- [Vagrant 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077850/vagrant-403-forbidden)

Trying to find a solution. I created a new project from scratch to test if I was able to use VVV on a fresh installation. The installation ran without problems However, I get the same error trying to load any of the 4 Sites from VVV.

Before this I was able to create as many VM and VVV was working like a charm. I don't know what could've changed.

Comment: I have same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Guerrilla I couldn't find it. I ended up reinstalling wiping my setup and reinstalling VVV (exactly what I didn't want to do). My vagrant is working fine right now.

Comment: Tried that twice.  Guess something else must be awry for me.  Thanks for replying